# Meaning of additional gray circles that show up in VS Code TypeScript debugger

Tags: typescript, debugging, vscode-extensions

I run VS Code 1.73 and debug VS Code main branch commit `156cc97c88232275391e23f141423cd93b921ddd`.

I put couple of breakpoints in `src/vs/editor/common/languages/linkComputer.ts` file:
[image: breakpoints].

Then I start debugging, and to trigger breakpoint on `return result;` I create new text file via main menu: File > New Text File. After a 1-2 sec. breakpoint on `return result;` is hit, but additional gray circles show up on lines 293, 335, 340.

[image: Additional gray circles]

What is the point in them? How do they work?

Comment: You can set breakpoints on specific parts of the line instead of just the start of the line.

Comment: But how breakpoint after `result.` or after `LinkComputer.` or after `return result;` is different from the breakpoint on the start of the line on the corresponding lines?